# Sequential sequence containers OR How to pack vectors

Tags: c++, boost, stl, std

Imagine I have two vectors:

```
std::vector<int> A,B;
//Push a bunch of data into A
//Push a bunch of data into B
```

For whatever reason, I want to create an interface to these vectors such as follows:

```
packed combined(A,B);
for(packed::iterator i=combined.begin();i!=combined.end();++i)
  *i+=1;
```

This will have the same effect as:

```
for(std::vector::iterator i=A.begin();i!=A.end();++i)
  *i+=1;
for(std::vector::iterator i=B.begin();i!=B.end();++i)
  *i+=1;
```

I could code up a class to do this, but it seems like the code may already exist in a library somewhere. Does anyone know if this is the case?

Alternatively, can you think of a *cunning* way to do this?

Comment: did you already ask Blackadder?

Comment: I tried, @rhalbersma, but he slipped away and escaped before I could ask him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[boost::join](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html):

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/join.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3}, b = {4,5,6};
    for(int& i : boost::join(a, b)) {
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for some reason I didn't think of boost.join but the more fragile zip iterators